# Google map api v3 doesnt appear when plotting markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I was following this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mkOVjRz3tg
but grabbing info from my DB instead and my map just appeared as a white screen with no map.
I had this running on an android app but then I had too many dots to plot that the android app stopped working so I am trying to make it a web interface. Any help would be appreciated. Also this is my first time dealing with `js`
a snippet of the json looks like:

```
{
  "coords": [
    {
      "latitude": "33.702908",
      "longitude": "-86.370771",
      "id": ""
    },
    {
      "latitude": 0,
      "longitude": 0,
      "id": "(null)"
    },
    {
      "latitude": "0.000000",
      "longitude": "0.000000",
      "id": "00004561-CE13-4125-A244-989D2E984A91"
    },
    {
      "latitude": "33.273388",
      "longitude": "-86.832977",
      "id": "0000F355-43B0-4164-9CD4-0D7C57A1B37C"
    }
  ]
}
```

Html + js

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simple markers</title>
  <style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

  <script >

function getUserLocs(callback){
  $.getJSON('http://www.url.com', callback)
}

  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'H'
    });

    getUserLocs(function(data){
      var locs = data.coords;
      for (i in locs) {
        var lat = locs[i];
        var lon = locs[i];
        latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'H'

      });

    }) LINE 51 this where the syntax error is
  }


  </script>
  <script>
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

errors: SyntaxError: syntax error map.html:51

Comment: any messages in console?

Comment: just put errors at the bottom of the question

Comment: Do you insert "width: 100%" into the <style> tag?

Comment: just tried it didnt make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss one "}" after the creating marker.

```
    getUserLocs(function(data){
      var locs = data.coords;
      for (i in locs) {
        var lat = locs[i];
        var lon = locs[i];
        latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'H'
        });
      }   // <-- here
    });
```

Comment: thanks but for some reason my markers are not plotting any idea why that is

Answer (score 1):

To map the markers from JSON, you need to change your code:

```
    getUserLocs(function(data){
      var locs = data.coords;
      for (i in locs) {
        var lat = parseFloat(locs[i].latitude, 10);
        var lon = parseFloat(locs[i].longitude, 10);
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'H'
        });
      }
    });
```

http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/tmp/stackoverflow/21196413/test.html
[image]

Comment: still no luck with that :(

Comment: It's toooo much data. In this case, Fusion Table is suite for you. Fusion Table provides API so you can insert data programatically, and you can implement it onto map easily using Fusion Table Layers. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables